# PHP - Declare variable in if statement and use it in the same statement

Tags: php, if-statement, declaration, php-7

I want to declare a variable in a `if` statement and use it in the same statement. Is this simply not possible?

Example of problem (not actual use case though...):

```
if ($test = array('test'=>5) && $test['test'] === 5) {
    echo 'test';
} else {
    echo 'nope';
}
```

Error message:

> NOTICE Undefined variable: test on line number 6

Comment: Operator precedence: `if (($test = array('test'=>5)) && $test['test'] === 5) {
    echo 'test';
} else {
    echo 'nope';
}` though I wouldn't consider this good coding practise

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks! Why do you not consider this a good coding practise?

Comment: Why would you ever really need to do this? Just curious on the actual usability of this, I can't think of a scenario where it's useful.

Comment: Assigning variables inside if expressions can lead to confusion and errors. Someone else (or even you at a later point in time) can't be sure if it was meant to be an assignment or an invalid comparison.

Comment: This way I can check whether a record is successfully retrieved AND is the compatible with a previously retrieved record, all in one statement. Otherwise I would have to nest if statements. with each else having to do the exact same thing (`404 not found`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) you will need to group the assignment with `()`:

```
if ( ($test = array('test'=>5)) && $test['test'] === 5) {
    echo 'test';
} else {
    echo 'nope';
}
```

A simple use case might be:

```
if ( ($parts = parse_url($url)) && $parts['port'] == 8080) {
    // do stuff
}
```